# Add custom anchors/links when converting HTML to PDF with iText(Sharp)

Tags: c#, html, pdf, itext, itext7

How can I add custom anchor and/or link to the html page I am converting to pdf?

From my understanding it should be done by using Chunks, however I am not sure how exactly in this case.
I tried implementing TagWorker, but there doesn't seem to be any way to add Chunk in there, nor add anchor/link in any other way.
I also tried adding Chunk as a child node when looping over the elements coming from HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(), but had no luck either.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why do you need to change the html DURING conversion?  Why not modify the HTML to add the links, then convert the result to pdf.

Comment: Honestly, that never even crossed my mind. From what I can think of right now, that should work just fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Neil Sadly, it doesn't work, at least not out of the box. When I replace the anchors in the html, itext then adds the original url when converting to elements, which breaks it. There might be a way to modify the processing, but I don't know how to do so :(

Comment: So the problem is with the conversion process then, not the HTML?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Sounds like you need to investigate a different method of converting to PDF.  I used https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ which is free (it has its own issues, but might be worth checking out if it works for your use-case).

Comment: Actually, I think I will just nab the internal method and modify it to not do this ;D